# Plot a bar graph between two sets of non-numerical data and label by product type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have filtered my dataset such that I grouped ages of individuals in age bins as follows:

[image]

I would like to plot a bargraph with age_bins on the x-axis and the count of product on the y axis.

For each bar plot, I would like it split three-way to show the grouping by product type i.e TM195, TM498, or TM798

What is the simplest way I can go about this?

```
Product age_bins    Gender
0   TM195   (17, 26]    Male
1   TM195   (17, 26]    Male
2   TM195   (17, 26]    Female
3   TM195   (17, 26]    Male
4   TM195   (17, 26]    Male
... ... ... ...
175 TM798   (36, 46]    Male
176 TM798   (36, 46]    Male
177 TM798   (36, 46]    Male
178 TM798   (46, 50]    Male
179 TM798   (46, 50]    Male
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope your data is more diverse than the sample. Try

```
import matplotlib .pyplot as plt
df.groupby('Product')['age_bins'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: @Ossz Does that help? Let us know if you need further help

Comment: Hi @wwnde thanks a lot for your input. I'm afraid when implementing this I am getting **Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)** error and am unsure why?

Comment: Please provide non image data sample.

Comment: Hi @wwnde, I've included a non-image data sample above in the main question body I posted. Cheers.